# exceptions.TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def imageMoments(img):
    #Single channel(8 bit or floating point 2D array)  
    read_original = cv2.imread(img)

    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnt = contours[0]

    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    print M

    cx = int(M[’m10’]/M[’m00’])
    cy = int(M[’m01’]/M[’m00’])
    return
```

I get the error

```
src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Comment: So look at what error says, it's not a numpy array,neither a scalar.

Comment: Please always include the **full** traceback of Python exceptions. You need to give us some sample input and expected output too here. And did your editor change the quotes around `’m10’`, etc. to fancy quotes? That's not valid syntax for Python, at any rate.

Answer (score 3):

`cv2.threshold` requires a *gray-scale image* for an argument, not a string representing a filename.  Thus, replace:

```
read_original = cv2.imread(img)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, 0)
```

With:

```
read_original = cv2.imread(img)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(read_original,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
```

In the original code, the string `img` is passed as an argument to `threshold`.  In the revised code, the argument to `threshold` is instead a gray-scale image, `imgray`.